# HTML5 required hidden file field - feedback location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a hidden file field that is styled via button and text field:

```
<input class="form-control" disabled="true" id="qsd_filename" placeholder="Upload a file to submit. Limit: 512 kb" type="text">
<input id="qsd_upload" name="dr[etq[]][eta][file]" required="required" type="file">
<span class="input-group-btn right-btn">
    <a class="btn btn-primary left-btn browse-button" id="qsd_link">Browse</a>
</span>
```

The javascript I have (which works) will change the filename text field when hidden upload is triggered by the link.

My issue is the "required" part of this. If I require the hidden file field, it will prevent the submission as desired, but it will create feedback up at the top left corner of the screen. If I make the text field required, it does nothing.

How do I get a hidden file field to have its feedback near it?

Comment: The visual appearance of the `required` attribute introduced in HTML5 depends on the browser (engine). If the feedback is displayed on the top left (zero point), the browser attempts to place it next to the corresponding element, which is hidden in your case and thus does not have a position to render to. Did you try `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`?

Comment: That almost works! I set the height to 0 as well, but it seems to still be taking up space.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `if upload field is invalid, make the text field invalid with this message` but I can't figure that out.

Comment: Well, it works well enough if I change it to `visibility: hidden` and set both `height` and `width` to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not perfect, but a pretty good answer (thanks to @MVP), just changed the file field style to:

```
visibility: hidden 
height: 0;
width: 0;
```

The downside to this is the feedback is not *quite* in the right spot, but it is much closer.